# What does the word 「こったい」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

The sentence said by a boy who looks like being angry because of something.

なんでもねえやこっちの**こったい**! なんにしてもおれはでねえぞっ　一歩だってこの　ひみつ練習場を...

I have found that several Japanese forums told that「なんてこったい」 means "What the hell" or "Oh my god" but I'm not sure what just the word alone really means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

こっちのこったい is a colloquial contraction of こっちのことだい, *lit.* It is a matter of my/our side, → "It's not your concern." "It's none of your business."

Compare:
なんてこったい！ → なんてことだい "What the hell?"
いやなこったい！ → いやなことだい (≂ いやだ) "No way!"

Ending a sentence with ～だい is Tokyo/Edo dialect (I think), e.g. 「行くんだい！」「何言ってんだい！」

---

なんでもねえや → It's nothing.
こっちのこったい! → Mind your own business.
なんにしても → In any case,
おれはでねえぞっ → I'll never get out (of this...)
一歩だって → not even a single step
このひみつ(の?)練習場を... → (... get out) of this secret gym / training room...

Comment: (extinct) Tokyo dialect (I think)

Answer (score 1):

こっちのこったい is casual expression of こっちのことです

In this case, こったい is same meaning as ことです

こっちのこと means my own business

So こっちのこったい means it is my own business.